# Room dao is slow - android

Tags: android, android-room, dao

I am using `Room` in my project but when I use `insert` or `update` it is slow.

My code for `Select` is (`DialogFragment`):

```
    class LangsListDialogFragment: DaggerAppCompatDialogFragment(), LangsListAdapter.LangListListener {

    @BindView(R.id.rcvLangsFilter)
    lateinit var rcvLangsFilter: RecyclerView

    @Inject
    lateinit var langListDialogViewModel: LangsListDialogViewModel
    @Inject
    lateinit var langsListAdapter: LangsListAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_langs_list, container);
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view)

        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        layoutManager.orientation = RecyclerView.VERTICAL
        rcvLangsFilter.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        rcvLangsFilter.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(
                activity,
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
            )
        )

        fillFromDao()
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.icBtnCloseLangsFilter)
    fun icBtnCloseLangsFilterClick(){
        dismiss()
    }

    private fun fillFromDao() {
        val notesObserver: Observer<List<Language?>?>? =
            Observer { langs: List<Language?>? ->
                langsListAdapter.setLangs(langs)
                rcvLangsFilter.adapter = langsListAdapter
            }
        if (notesObserver != null) {
            langListDialogViewModel.fetchLangsModel()?.observe(this, notesObserver)
        }
    }

    override fun onCheckBoxStatus(id_language: Int?, id: Int?, symbol: String?, isSelected: Boolean) {
        langListDialogViewModel.updateChecked(id_language, id, symbol, isSelected)
    }
}
```

And in my `ViewModel`:

```
class LangsListDialogViewModel @Inject constructor(application: Application) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val executor: Executor =
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    private val appRepository: AppRepository =
        AppRepository.getInstance(application.applicationContext)!!

    fun fetchLangsModel(): LiveData<List<Language?>?>? {
        val callable = Callable { appRepository.selectLangsAppRepo() }
        val future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(callable)
        return future.get()

    }

    fun updateChecked(id_language: Int?, id: Int?, symbol: String?, isSelected: Boolean) {
        executor.execute {
            appRepository.updateCheckedAppRepo(id_language, id, symbol, isSelected)
        }
    }
}
```

And my `Repository` is:

```
class AppRepository private constructor(context: Context) {
    private val appDatabase: AppDatabase? = AppDatabase.getInstance(context)

    companion object {
        private var ourInstance: AppRepository? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppRepository? {
            if (ourInstance == null) {
                ourInstance = AppRepository(context)
            }
            return ourInstance
        }
    }
 //region Langs List Dialog
    fun selectLangsAppRepo(): LiveData<List<Language?>?>? {
        return if (this.appDatabase?.coursesDao() != null) {
            appDatabase.langsListDao()!!.langsDB()
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    fun updateCheckedAppRepo(id_language: Int?, id: Int?, symbol: String?, isSelected: Boolean){
        if (this.appDatabase?.coursesDao() != null) {
            this.appDatabase.langsListDao()!!.updateChecked(id_language, id, symbol, isSelected)
        }
    }
    //endregion

}
```

And my `DAO` is:

```
@Dao
interface LangsListDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Language")
    fun langsDB(): LiveData<List<Language?>?>?

    @Query("UPDATE Language SET isSelectedLan = :isSelected WHERE id_language = :id_language AND id = :id AND symbol = :symbol")
    fun updateChecked(id_language: Int?, id: Int?, symbol: String?, isSelected: Boolean)
}
```

Comment: Your `fetchLangsModel()` is rather strange. You create a one-off `Executor`, ask it to do something on a background thread... and then immediately block waiting for that thread to complete. It would be simpler, faster, and more correct to have `fun fetchLangsModel(): LiveData<List<Language?>?>? = appRepository.selectLangsAppRepo()`. Beyond that, we cannot help you with a DAO without seeing the DAO. Also, we cannot help you with inserts and updates being slow if your code does not show any inserts and updates.

Comment: @  CommonsWare. I edited my question.

Comment: Make sure that you have appropriate indexes set up for your `UPDATE` statement's `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Can you get me sample, please.